# why <LimitExcept> parameter results "deny not allowed here" error in virtualhost tag?

Tags: configuration, apache2, webserver

in apache's httpd.conf between `VirtualHost` tags I put `<LimitExcept>` expression like follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName geopreprod.avea.com.tr

 <LimitExcept HEAD POST GET>
     Deny from all
 </LimitExcept> 

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://XXXXXXXX...
  ProxyPassReverse / http://XXXXXXXX....
</VirtualHost>
```

and then apache web server fails to start by giving following error:

```
Syntax error on line 513 of XXXXX/httpd.conf:
deny not allowed here
```

Although it says `<LimitExcept>` can be used in `VirtualHost` tag in [offical docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept) why do I get this error?

in apache docs it says:

```
Context:    server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
```

Comment: Closed as cross-site post by same user: http://serverfault.com/questions/356493/apache2-why-limitexcept-parameter-results-deny-not-allowed-here-error-in-vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from serverfault, [here](https://serverfault.com/a/356503/108409)